How to translate strings from [file] upload tag in Contact Form 7?
I am using Contact Form 7 plugin to create a simple contact form with file upload option. For file upload CF7 inserts [file] tag. This tag renders a button with Choose File string and a string No file chosen near right to the button (if no files have been uploaded).
These strings are default for the file upload option and are not present neither in CF7 "Messages" tab for a given contact form, nor in "Translations" section of the Polylang plugin which I am using for website translations. I may need to translate these 2 strings.
I have found CF7 string translations there [1], and for my specific locale there [2].
But these strings seem to be missing in these links too.
I tried to inspect some of the CF7 plugin .php files (like file.php) for these strings and didn't find them there either.
I understand that for every translation language I'd need to create a new CF7 form with its strings translated. But there seems to be no access to these 2 strings. 
Can you advise on how to translate/get access to these 2 strings rendered by the CF7 file upload tag? Maybe you can indicate specific CF7 plugin files, where the file upload button code is handled along with the 2 strings mentioned above (so that I can translate directly in the plugin files, though then I'd also need to know which plugin files handle the newly created contact forms which I will create for each language)?
[1] https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/ 
[2] https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/lt/default/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/

As we know the strings "Choose File" and "No file chosen" in the file upload button of CF7 are not controlled by the plugin itself. These strings are part of the HTML  element and handled by the browser and the OS.
This is the reason, they are not present in the CF7 plugin's translation files or in the plugin's PHP files.

This worked for me in w3schools html playground: <input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" /> <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/> But CF7 seem to not allow lots of HTML with its tags? If I could switch to HTML editor in CF7 it would be better.  [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file
